# Does helm's `--dry-run` option need connection to kubernetes API server? Facing connection error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to test my development helm chat deployment output using `--dry-run` option.  when I run the below command its trying to connect to Kubernetes API server.

Is dry run option required to connect Kubernetes cluster? all I want to check the deployment yaml file output.

```
helm install mychart-0.1.0.tgz --dry-run --debug

Error: Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dhelm%2Cname%3Dtiller: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Comment: Here is really good youtube tutorial for understanding the helm dry run install - https://youtu.be/gb5nYiWAIUs

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As stated on [Helm's documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started.md)

> When you want to test the template rendering, but not actually install anything, you can use helm install --debug --dry-run ./mychart. This will send the chart to the Tiller server, which will render the templates. But instead of installing the chart, it will return the rendered template to you so you can see the output

So it still needs to connect to Tiller to render your templates with the right values. The difference when using the --dry-run option is that it won't actually install the chart.

Comment: Eldad AK's answer is simpler and does not require a Tiller server.

Comment: Tiller is removed after helm 3.0.0, which is perceived as security potential.

Answer (score 125):

There is also an option to run `helm template ./mychart` to render the generated YAMLs without needing the connection to tiller.
Combined with `helm lint` it's a great set to verify validity of your chart.

Comment: This answer should be the validated one. Using rancher, we don't have possibility to make a "dry-run" as there is no accessible Tiler. `helm template` is a very simple way to check the output of templates. Thanks !

Comment: @Metal3d But helm template does not contain the actual value that will be installed, so in many cases, helm install with --dry-run option is the best one to get the actual values instead of templates.

Comment: Now that helm v3 is out, it's much easier to run the `--dry-run` option.

Comment: Note that currently the difference between `helm install --dry-run` and `helm template` is that with the latter, the `NOTES.txt` file is not rendered. Which may be a problem when the workflow involves `helm template` and `kubectl apply -f`. See https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6901

Answer (score 25):

There is a small diff between `helm install --dry-run` and `helm template` command:

- `helm install --dry-run` will send your chart to the tiller which
  will verify and render the manifest files against the K8S specs along with the
  YAML validations.
- `helm template` will only generate the manifest and verify if your YAML file is valid. However, it won't check if the generated manifests are valid Kubernetes resources. Ref: [Helm Docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/#synopsis)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Helm template` or `helm lint` instead.

`helm lint` i*s your go-to tool for verifying that your chart follows best practices*.